Kotlin multiplatform - shared.framework not being linked
I've created a new Kotlin Multiplatform project using the Android Studio wizard without Cocoapods. Everything works fine on Android but I can't link the shared.framerwork in Xcode because of the following error:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shared:assembleDebugAppleFrameworkForXcodeIosX64' (type 'FrameworkCopy').

  - Type 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.apple.FrameworkCopy' property 'sourceFramework' specifies directory '/Documents/Development/multiplatform/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework' which doesn't exist.

I've changed a bit the structure of the shared module in order to have a more modular project and this is the resulting structure:

Also, this is the build.gradle.kts in :shared:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true

            if (System.getenv("XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR") == "1500") {
                linkerOpts += "-ld64"
            }
            
            // Export modules to iOS
            export(project(":shared:core"))
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // Accessible by the native app
            api(project(":shared:core"))
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.my.project"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

And this is the build.gradle.kts in :shared:core:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true

            if (System.getenv("XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR") == "1500") {
                linkerOpts += "-ld64"
            }
     }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // Add dependencies here
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.my.project"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

Using Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 and Xcode: 15.2. Any ideas where the problem might be?

There are too many possibilities to cause this problem. You can break down your code from the beginning to the last condition. At the same point, you can figure out the error.
For example, I commented out almost all my code because of its complicated structure. In the end, I found the "Kotlinx Serialization Contextual" caused the linking issue. It's not compatible with KMP.
